# Z-index problem with hover when dealing with clip-path objects

Tags: html, css, z-index, clip-path

I'm having some problems I'm trying to have two clip path polygons overlap each other when hovered over by the mouse, I'm using z-index's and trying to change them depending on with overlay is being hovered over but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried changing the z-index when the object is hovered over but that doesn't seem to change anything.

```css
.banner {
position:relative;
    bottom 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

.overlayleft {
position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    bottom 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlayright {
position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    bottom: 0;
    top 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 25% 100%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: .5s ease;

}

.overlayleft:hover{
z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlayright:hover{
z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="overlayright"></div>  
      <div class="overlayleft"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this "background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);"

Its color with opacity, if you change the color to something else, lets say red color,  you will see the difference.

Basically left div is black, and the second div is gray, when gray one is hovered its not visible that it is hovering the left one because of its opacity...